# How to install pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to install pygame for 3.3 and 3.4 and can't find a way to install it probably with out it giving a error when I do `pygame.init()`.

Is it because `pygame.init()` is not the proper code or is it because I installed it incorrectly?  If so, can someone tell me how to install it?

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please include more details about the error, and other installation details. No need to be cryptic.

Answer (score 15):

You can find binary installations for pygame for python 3.4 on windows [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). I'm not sure where you could find it if you're running a different operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Check out downloads on their bitbucket repo (for windows):
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

Answer (score 2):

On Windows: open your comandline and type:

```
   pip install pygame
```

On Debian-based Linux type into your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Comment: As pygame appeared in the PIP reository I think it is the best way to do that for now. You can use pip on linux too but with *sudo* if installing to a global system interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Gohlke's precompiled pythonlibs in wheel format :) [pygame from Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

I was never let down by those libraries and I used numpy, scipy, scikit-learn etc. (and pygame as well) extensively, which are one of the tougher to build on windows ;)