# How to fix the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'"?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I wanted to "compile" the project on pygame using pyinstaller, but when opening the .exe file, this error pops up:

[image]

Comment: The error is right there, run `pip install pygame`

Comment: The `pygame` module is not installed on your device. Press Win+R>Type `cmd`>Press Enter> Type `pip install pygame`>Press Enter. Wait for it to install and the problem would be solved

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra it didn't help. pygame was installed before that. When I try to install writes: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\ав\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.0.2)

Comment: In the application you are using to execute the programs make sure you have selected the python interpreter at the path you mentioned i.e.`c:\users\ab\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133462/how-to-install-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

this could happen because either you havent installed pygame
do `pip install pygame` to fix that or might be because python is not added to you path in environment variable [steps to add python to path](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)
or it might be that you haven't installed python [check here to install it](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)